# babel package affects nested list

Tags: itemize, babel

I have a problem with `babel`package. Here is a minimal working example with `\usepackage[french]{babel}` commented.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
 \usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table des mati\`eres}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=red,
   urlcolor=blue,
   pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature},
   pdfauthor={Dimitrios Papas}]{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter-pages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hyperref[ToC-first-page]{Jump to Contents}}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection% Place hyperlink marker
  \label{ToC-first-page}% Set \label for hyperlink
  \oldtableofcontents
}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \clearpage
  \oldmainmatter
  \pagestyle{mainmatter-pages}%
}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

\newcommand{\FIG}[2]
{
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\centering{\includegraphics[]{#1}}
\caption{\label{#1}\small{#2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt

\begin{document}

\title{DOSSIER DE CANDIDATURE}
\author{Dimitrios Papas\thanks{vbkvbkvbdkvbd}}

\affil{
Université\ldots}

\date{\begin{center}
Docteur en Mécanique
\end{center}}

\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter  

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter  

\chapter{First}

\section{First section}

\section{Expérience professionnelle}

 blablabla

\begin{description}

\item Depuis 09/2016
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

This work as desired. But uncommented the `\usepackage[french]{babel}` seems to conflict with the nested `itemize` environment.
I need this package for characters like `guillemotleft` (and right) etc.

Any workaround? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not use the french option only to get characters, but only if you want to write your article in french. Beside this: You can try `\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}`. Check the documentation of  babel-french of more options to influence the layout changes made by frenchb.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the comment. In fact it is a french document!

Comment: As far as I remeber, as soon as you load `enumitem` to customise your lists, `frenchb` does not interfere. Comment aside,: you should use `geometry` to change the default layout of the page.

Comment: @Bernard I add the suggested package but I still face the same problem. There is no any difference between items and subitems (apart from indentation of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `\setlist` command from `enumitem`. Incidentally, I added  `\uspackage[T1]{fontenc}` and loaded the `Latin Modern` fonts for a correct hyphenaion of accented letters. I also suppose you want `a4paper`, and preferably, load `frenchb` as a document class option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
 \usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table des mati\`eres}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=red,
   urlcolor=blue,
   pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature},
   pdfauthor={Dimitrios Papas}]{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter-pages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hyperref[ToC-first-page]{Jump to Contents}}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection% Place hyperlink marker
  \label{ToC-first-page}% Set \label for hyperlink
  \oldtableofcontents
}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \clearpage
  \oldmainmatter
  \pagestyle{mainmatter-pages}%
}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

\newcommand{\FIG}[2]
{
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\centering{\includegraphics[]{#1}}
\caption{\label{#1}\small{#2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\parindent0pt \parskip10pt

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=\textendash}


\begin{document}

\title{DOSSIER DE CANDIDATURE}
\author{Dimitrios Papas\thanks{vbkvbkvbdkvbd}}

\affil{
Université\ldots}

\date{\begin{center}
Docteur en Mécanique
\end{center}}

\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\section{First section}

\section{Expérience professionnelle}

 blablabla

\begin{description}

\item Depuis 09/2016
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]